Restoring Gnome after KDE
In an effort to fix some Remote desktop issues, I thought I would try KDE. Which I tried but was a bit buggy. But I'm not able to go back to gnome. I just get the text based login. I've tried reinstalling ubuntu desktop, but nothing is working.

You've not provided many specifics; we don't know what Ubuntu release you're asking about, what packages you actually installed to achieve KDE Plasma, nor what you removed...  Installing a different desktop can also change themes & more that will impact other desktops (even though KDE Plasma is Qt & GNOME is GTK; apps run on the desktop don't always match the desktop itself thus there is some overlap).  You mention re-installing & text only login, but gave no details of what you actually re-installed & what messages you get (did you explore logs? were any warnings issued? etc)
